# How to Implement Multi Select Dropdown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for a good way to create multi select dropdowns in plain React, without using an additional library.

At present, I’m doing something like this:

```
<select className='yearlymeeting' multiple={true}>
    <option value=''>Yearly Meeting</option>
    {
        this.state.meeting.yearly_meeting.map((m: Meeting, i: number) => {
            return (
                <option
                    value={m.title}
                    key={i}
                    selected={this.state.selectedTitles.yearlyMeetingTitles.includes(m.title) ? true : false}>
                    {m.title}
                </option>
             );
         })
     }
</select>
```

This code "works", but I'm getting this warning:

```
Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.
```

Comment: ok...so what part of that error message isn't clear? And what is your specific question? Did you try doing what the message suggests? Or look in the react docs for `<select>`?

Answer (score 3):

From react docs -

> You can pass an array into the value attribute, allowing you to select multiple options in a select tag:

```
<select multiple={true} value={['B', 'C']}>
```

I think you just need to pass your selected items array to value prop of select element.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I didn't realize you could pass in an array here. Makes total sense. By the way, here's a link to the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking conditions and setting "selected" props in the "option" element, directly set the value in the "select" element. The warning should go away.

```
<select className='yearlymeeting' multiple={true} 
value={this.state.selectedTitles.yearlyMeetingTitles}>
<option value=''>Yearly Meeting</option>
{
    this.state.meeting.yearly_meeting.map((m: Meeting, i: number) => {
        return (
            <option
                value={m.title}
                key={i}
                {m.title}
            </option>
         );
     })
 }
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Thank you! My blockage here was that it didn't occur to me that I could pass in an array for `value`